# Can you use `kafkacat` with AWS IAM Access Control

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-msk, kcat

I'm trying to use IAM Access Policy for authorization with MSK.
I was trying to follow https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/iam-access-control.html#configure-clients-for-iam-access-control.

Looks like `kafkacat` doesn't support it. The error I get is: `No such configuration property: "sasl.jaas.config "`. Am I missing something?

Comment: JAAS is a Java thing. kafkacat is written in C... No, [there is no JAAS config for it](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md)